# how to get float as well as int from a python string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
for key in x: 
    if(key=='data'):
        dd = dd.from_dict(x[key])
        dd = dd[:5]

for row in dd.iterrows():
    y = str(row)
    m = re.findall("\d+\.\d+|\d+",y)
    print(m)
```

I am trying to get some int and float from a string using this code. The problem what I am facing is `m=re.findall("\d+\.\d+|\d+",y)` is not working as I expected.

Input dataframe is :

```
0  [2019-10-14T09:15:00+0530, 232.55, 235.2, 231.7, 233, 80683, 0]    
1  [2019-10-14T09:20:00+0530, 233, 233, 231.4, 231.8, 53296, 0]       
2  [2019-10-14T09:25:00+0530, 231.8, 232.8, 231.1, 231.2, 41238, 0]   
3  [2019-10-14T09:30:00+0530, 231.25, 231.4, 230.6, 231.4, 31558, 0]  
4  [2019-10-14T09:35:00+0530, 231.4, 231.75, 230.95, 231.05, 29480, 0]
```

Output is:

```
['0', '2019', '10', '14', '09', '15', '00', '0530', '232.55', '235.2', 
'231.7', '233', '80683', '0', '0']
['1', '2019', '10', '14', '09', '20', '00', '0530', '233', '233', '231.4', 
'231.8', '53296', '0', '1']
['2', '2019', '-10', '-14', '09', '25', '00', '0530', '231.8', '232.8', '231.1', '231.2', '41238', '0', '2']
```

Expected output is :

```
[ '232.55', '235.2', '231.7', '233', '80683','0']
[ '233', '233', '231.4', '231.8', '53296','0']
[ '231.8', '232.8', '231.1', '231.2', '41238','0']
```

Comment: The output is:['0', '2019', '-10', '-14', '09', '15', '00', '0530', '232.55', '235.2', '231.7', '233', '80683', '0', '0']
['1', '2019', '-10', '-14', '09', '20', '00', '0530', '233', '233', '231.4', '231.8', '53296', '0', '1']
['2', '2019', '-10', '-14', '09', '25', '00', '0530', '231.8', '232.8', '231.1', '231.2', '41238', '0', '2']

Comment: Now that the question is updated, you'll get better answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date is always first in your list you could simply use the str built-in .split() method as well as list slicing.

In your case i believe replacing

```
m = re.findall("\d+\.\d+|\d+",y)
```

by

```
m = y.split(',')[1:] #splits 'y' str into list and takes elements from index 1 to end
```

should work if the element you wish to dispose of is always the first.